# How can I replace an existing image on a winforms ImageList?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, imagelist

How can I replace an existing image on a winforms `ImageList`?

I tried this:

```
this.CoolPics.Images [ 2 ] = // new image
this.ListViewControl.SmallImageList = this.CoolPics;
```

However the new image is not rescaled the way the others are, when I used the `this.CoolPics.Images.Add` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but here is how I solved the problem.  It looks like the image list will not resize the image upon assignment (even though it does when using the Add() function).  So basically, you need to resize the image manually before assigning.

```
Image img; //used to load new image from disk
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(160, 120); //canvas where the new image will be drawn/resized
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); //used to draw/resize the new image

img = new Bitmap(fileDialog.FileNames[0]); //load new image from disk

graph.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 120)); //resize new image to proper size

imgList.Images[index] = bmp; //assign the new resized image to the list (overwrites the old image)
```

Answer (score 0):

after your code try

```
listView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try today.

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. It changed the image but the image wasn't rescaled like when I first added the images.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before and if I remember right the assignment operator had this behavior but the Imagelist.Images.Add(myImage) did the right thing.

Try changing your code to do the .Add(myImage) and see if that doesn't look better.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with that would be that I would have to either remove the old one, which would change the other listview items (?) or the imagelist would grow with unused items.

Comment: I don't know why the ImageList ImageCollection has a RemoveAt but not an Insert. Seems to be missing functionality. Total hack but you could Add it, save the returned index of the add, use the = to assign the index you want with the new index, then use RemoveAt to remove the added one with the saved index...